# Looking for cross-platform browser control

Tags: c#, mono, webbrowser-control

Currently I am working on a `C#` Windows Application and also working on mono. 
My goal is to run `C#` Windows Application on Ubuntu like below:

```
mono HelloWorld.exe
```

It runs pretty well in Ubuntu with mono. Now I have to add a web browser control onto my `C#` application. I tried DotNetBrowser, but officially answered that they do not support on Linux. I was looking for Edge via Microsoft Toolkit, but I haven't tested it yet. Can anyone suggest me a good web browser control which fits my goal?

1. Should work on C# Windows Application
2. Multi-thread(multi browser instance)  supported
3. Should be able to handle cookies(Like CookieCollection to browser and browser to CookieCollection)
4. Modern HTML5 and css supported
5. Commercial or non-commercial both are ok

**Case 1:** First of all, I tried Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView, which was known as Edge browser.
And here is the error I was informed.

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.OSVersionHelper' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: ntdll.dll assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
 at (wrapper managed-to-native) Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.Win32.NativeMethods._RtlGetVersion(Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.Win32.OSVERSIONINFOEX&)
 at Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.Win32.NativeMethods.RtlGetVersion () [0x00020] in <cbb7d2346bc74d6bae671e0688cf654e>:0
 at Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.OSVersionHelper.IsServer () [0x00000] in <cbb7d2346bc74d6bae671e0688cf654e>:0
 at Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.OSVersionHelper..cctor () [0x00042] in <cbb7d2346bc74d6bae671e0688cf654e>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView.System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize.EndInit () [0x0001b] in <cbb7d2346bc74d6bae671e0688cf654e>:0
 at HelloWorld.Form1.InitializeComponent () [0x000fe] in <9bf85b488e054a42957cd1546d4697e1>:0
 at HelloWorld.Form1..ctor () [0x0000f] in <9bf85b488e054a42957cd1546d4697e1>:0
 at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) HelloWorld.Form1..ctor()
 at HelloWorld.Program.Main () [0x0000e] in <9bf85b488e054a42957cd1546d4697e1>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.OSVersionHelper' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: ntdll.dll assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
 at (wrapper managed-to-native) Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.Win32.NativeMethods._RtlGetVersion(Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.Win32.OSVERSIONINFOEX&)
 at Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.Win32.NativeMethods.RtlGetVersion () [0x00020] in <cbb7d2346bc74d6bae671e0688cf654e>:0
 at Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.OSVersionHelper.IsServer () [0x00000] in <cbb7d2346bc74d6bae671e0688cf654e>:0
 at Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.OSVersionHelper..cctor () [0x00042] in <cbb7d2346bc74d6bae671e0688cf654e>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView.System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize.EndInit () [0x0001b] in <cbb7d2346bc74d6bae671e0688cf654e>:0
 at HelloWorld.Form1.InitializeComponent () [0x000fe] in <9bf85b488e054a42957cd1546d4697e1>:0
 at HelloWorld.Form1..ctor () [0x0000f] in <9bf85b488e054a42957cd1546d4697e1>:0
 at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) HelloWorld.Form1..ctor()
 at HelloWorld.Program.Main () [0x0000e] in <9bf85b488e054a42957cd1546d4697e1>:0
```

**Case 2:** Now I changed the web browser control to the default one in Visual Studio.NET which is System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.
And I get this error.

```
libgluezilla not found. To have webbrowser support, you need libgluezilla installed
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
 at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Navigate (System.Uri url) [0x0001f] in <7346aaf818a24e898fc55461ebf690ad>:0
 at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Navigate(System.Uri)
 at HelloWorld.Form1.Form1_Load (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00011] in <d015c6fb9c2242c3b1ad5c571e8f4c27>:0
 at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad (System.EventArgs e) [0x0001f] in <7346aaf818a24e898fc55461ebf690ad>:0
 at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoadInternal (System.EventArgs e) [0x00023] in <7346aaf818a24e898fc55461ebf690ad>:0
```

**Case 2-2:** So, I checked if my Ubuntu has libgluezilla with terminal.

```
apt-cache search libgluezilla
```

And the return message is below.

```
libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil - Mono Web Browser library (for CLI 4.0)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is way too broad for us to answer, currently you are asking for recommendations which is off topic unfortunately. As a member of 8+ years, you've thought to post what you have tried and what isn't working for us to help you.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ My explanation was not good enough. I am adding some more errors I received.